# Finding the roots of simultaneous equations like these

Tags: systems-of-equations, roots, quadratics, cubics

[image]

I am unable to find the answer to this question. It would also be helpful if you post what areas of mathematics this relates to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand $(a+b+c)^3$, giving

$$a^3+b^3+c^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+3b^2c+3bc^3+3c^2b+3cb^2+6abc\\
=3(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)-2(a^3+b^3+c^3)+6abc.$$

$$7^3=3\cdot35\cdot7-2\cdot151+6abc$$

$$abc=15.$$

Comment: 9 minutes! This is outrageous! I expected a quicker delivery from this site. Haha. Thank you sir!

Comment: @ChrisWilliams: yep, sorry I wasted a little time believing that I should expand $(a+b+c)^2$ as well... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
(a+b+c)^2&=&a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca) \\
a^3+b^3+c^3 -3abc&=&(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-(ab+bc+ca))
\end{eqnarray*}
Use the first equation to obtain a value for $ab+bc+ca$ and the second to obtain a value for $abc$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)$$

Now use

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-(ab+bc+ca))$$